# I need a practical example for SWR with the fallback option

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fallback, swr

I'm trying to understand better how SWR works paired up with NextJS. I have over studied the example shown in the [SWR - Next.JS SSG and SSR tab](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs#pre-rendering-with-default-data), but I am still confused as how to get the data from an external API:

Why does the example from the hyperlink above uses '/api/article' as a key?

Is the useSWR hook going to grab this key and navigate to this destination?

Can I use an external API response such as "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"?

What do I put as a value inside the fallback object?

This is a simple snippet that I used to tinker with the fallback option. I do get a 1/4th of a second view of the data being displayed in the browser and it goes away turning into "John Doe".

```
import useSWR from "swr"

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(x=>x.json())

export default () =>{
    
    const {data, error} = useSWR("/api/hello", fetcher, {fallback:{"/api/hello":{name:"foo bar" }}})
    console.log(data)
    return <>{data && data.name}</>
}
```

I would like to see some other use cases where this feature would come in handy. If there's a link that I could get in order to understand this feature better, then that would be very beneficial to me.

I also tried to explain in my words to see if there is a mistake in my knowledge and I could be corrected if my logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, there is not much information on the web, so Let's suppose you want get data from the server side either using getServerSideProps or getStaticProps, but you don't want to pass to fallbackData, you want to have the data inside your request when the components mounts on the client.

in your _app

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, ...rest }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
  return (
    <SWRConfig
      value={{
        fallback: pageProps.fallback, //you extract the fallback when you run some code on the server and then it will be automatically injected to the provider
      }}
    >
      {getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </SWRConfig>
  );
}
```

Now you already configured the provider, let's make an example

```js
const Home = () => {
  const { data } = useSWR("yourKey",fetcher);

  return (
    <>
      {data?.productsStoreFront.map((product) => (
        <div>{product.name}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

Home.getLayout = (page: ReactElement) => {
  return <MainLayout>{page}</MainLayout>;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const cheapestProducts = await GetProductsStoreFront();
  return {
    props: {
      fallback: {
         // it's important that you fallback key match with the key that you specify above
        ["yourKey"]: cheapestProducts,
      },
    },
  };
};
```

Hope it helps!